# Using a managed identity with Azure Service Bus

Tags: java, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

I want to use a managed identity to connect to Azure Service Bus. In the docs they mention the DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder. I don't really get how this would use my managed identity to authenticate to the Service Bus.

Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultAzureCredential` is a chained credential; internally it considers multiple authorization sources, including managed identities.   More information can be found in the [Azure.Identity overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable#defaultazurecredential).

Service Bus can use any of the [Azure.Identity credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable#credential-classes) for authorization. `DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder` is demonstrated only because it allows for success in a variety of scenarios.

If you'd prefer to restrict authorization to only a managed identity, you can do so by using `ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder` rather than the default credential.  An example of creating the can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com//java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable#authenticating-in-azure-with-managed-identity).  It can then be passed to Service Bus in the same manner as the default credential.

Comment: Thanks Jesse! It's a bit clearer for me now.